# Reading from sqlite3 remote databases

Tags: python, sqlite

In my server I'm trying to read from a bunch of sqlite3 databases (sent from web clients) and process their data. The db files are in an S3 bucket and I have their url and I can open them in memory.

Now the problem is `sqlite3.connect` only takes an absolute path string and I can't pass to it a file in memory.

```
conn=sqlite3.connect() #how to pass file in memory or url
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute('''select * from data;''')
res=c.fetchall()
# other processing with res
```

Comment: Why do you have a *remote* SQLite database?  That takes it well out of its scope of being embedded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLite *requires* database files to be stored on disk (it uses various locks and paging techniques). An in-memory file will not suffice.

I'd create a temporary directory to hold the database file, write it to that directory, *then* connect to it. The directory gives SQLite the space to write commit logs as well.

To handle all this, a context manager might be helpful:

```
import os.path
import shutil
import sqlite3
import sys
import tempfile

from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def sqlite_database(inmemory_data):
    path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    with open(os.path.join(path, 'sqlite.db'), 'wb') as dbfile:
        dbfile.write(inmemory_data)
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(path, 'sqlite.db'))
        yield conn
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(path)
        except IOError:
            sys.stderr.write('Failed to clean up temp dir {}'.format(path))
```

and use that as:

```
with sqlite_database(yourdata) as connection:
    # query the database
```

This writes in-memory data to disk, opens a connection, lets you use that connection, and afterwards cleans up after you.