# Creating SQLAlchemy engine from multiple SQLite databases in memory

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am very new to databases in general, so pardon my question if it is very simple. Right now I have to work on a task to do analytics and visualization from data in databases. I am forced to work with legacy code so my approach is something like this:

1. Create an SQLite database (call it A) in memory (I have to do this because I am given huge chunks of SQL scripts)
2. Create another distinct SQLite database (call it B) again in memory. With some looping, query and extract information out of database A, do a bit of combinations to them, and insert them into database B. Database B is now the database from which we will take data out from to perform analyses.

Starting from steps 3 and 4, I want to switch over to Python's `pandas`, a new move which the old codes did not have.

3. Convert that entire SQLite database B into a Python `pandas` DataFrame object
4. Perform analyses from that data taken from the DataFrame object (I do not want to continue these analyses with the SQLite database because it is much more tedious having to query it each time I need to extract the data I need, compared to if I were to use a DataFrame)

*However, the difficulty I am facing is that in moving from step 2 to 3, I do not know how I could actually safely have my database B be converted into an SQLAlchemy engine that would make it ready to be fed in `pandas` to form a DataFrame.*

As I read from the [pandas documentation on this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html?highlight=sql#sql-queries), and also the SQLAlchemy documentation on [SQLite](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#sqlite) and [in-memory databases](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/sqlite.html#using-a-memory-database-in-multiple-threads), all I am supposed to do to turn my SQLite database into the SQLAlchemy engine is to [tell SQLAlchemy that I want it to look for the database in memory](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/sqlite.html#connect-strings)

> The sqlite :memory: identifier is the default if no filepath is present. Specify sqlite:// and nothing else:

```
#in-memory database
e = create_engine('sqlite://')
```

However, for my case here, there are 2 databases A and B sitting in memory. In this case, how can I tell SQLAlchemy that I want it to take database B and not A? Is this a valid concern?

I hope to refactor the codes when I have the time. Can anyone suggest to me a more elegant way to move from step 1 to 4?

Comment: Or else, just write them to files instead of in-memory (or temporarily files if you don't need it afterwards)?

Comment: Otherwise, create a sqlite database in your temp directory, and clean it up (delete the files) after you are done. It is hardly more work than using an in-memory database. See [Reading from sqlite3 remote databases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21963088) for a sample context manager that creates a database and cleans it up afterwards (ignore the `inmemory_data` being written).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Its possible to have multiple in-memory databases. See https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: @joris and MartijnPieters Yes thank you both of you for your suggestions, especially MartijnPieters for the link. However, ideally what I was looking for was a what to be able to tell SQLAlchemy exactly which specific in memory database I want it to take. With the Python interface to SQLite, this is easy because we can have distinct connection and cursor objects for dfferent databases sitting in memory. I don't know why SQLAlchemy does not accept these 'handlers' for creating the engines.... Can someone explain please?

Comment: And it is not possible to create the in-memory databases from sqlalchemy and get the connection from there, instead of first creating the databases, and then connecting with them from sqlalchemy?

Comment: @joris Sorry I didn't quite get you. Do you mean i should try creating the in memory databases through SQLAlchemy rather than through SQLite?

Comment: yes, that is what I meant. Use twice `create_engine('sqlite://')` to have two in-memory databases with an engine associated.

Comment: @AKKO: sure, but **SQLAlchemy** doesn't support that usecase, not without additional hacking around the connection pool handling. Nor should you need to. I still don't get why you need separate databases here.

Comment: @joris: doesn't that just take the *same connection* from the already estapblished connection pool?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I also wasn't sure, but I tested it by creating two in memory engines, added a table to one, and it that table was not available in the other. So for such a simple test it seems to work, although have to admit I don't know it will still be valid for more complex cases. But I agree that it seems better to just have or one in-memory database, or work with temp files on disk.

Comment: @joris: then perhaps things have changed since I last tested that (which was way, way back in the 0.6 or 0.7 days anyway), or I misremembered this. Removed my comment.